# Help improving my bountied C# question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

How can I improve my question [Run a vb script using System.Diagnostics.Process but only partially successful in feeding in input text to the process' stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56731202/run-a-vb-script-using-system-diagnostics-process-but-only-partially-successful-i)?

It is not getting enough feedback, and I have even created a bounty.
Is it the title, or is it not being clear enough? I have already revised it to be more verbose...

Don't want to have my 50 rep points got wasted, tbh.

Comment: Bounties last seven days. You are only in day 1. You'll get more eyeballs as the bounty ages.

Comment: There isn't necessarily something wrong with your question, it is also possible that currently no one came around who knows the answer. A bounty _can_ help in this situation, but this is not guaranteed.

Comment: Seems fine to me. Questions that require knowledge on multiple domains (in this case, wsh + C#) get answers more slowly. Also, a bounty has most of its effect when it's about to expire, just wait and hope.

Comment: Thank you guys, about to have myself convinced that no one would care about whatever I put out